# Cosa significa "linea morbida" in questo contesto?

Tags: meaning

Devo tradurre [questo articolo](http://www.repubblica.it/motori/sezioni/sicurezza/2017/07/19/news/uso_del_cellulare_alla_guida_in_arrivo_la_rivoluzione-171167602/) in spagnolo, ma non so cos'è "linea morbida":

> Cambio, radicale, di rotta: in arrivo il pugno di ferro contro chi usa il cellulare alla guida: le polemiche suscitate dalla "**linea morbida**" e dalla clamorosa (e diciamolo pure, vergognosa) mancata risposta all'appello della Polizia Stradale ha dato i suoi frutti. È in arrivo la sospensione della patente già alla prima infrazione e raddoppio delle multe.

Ho cercato su alcuni dizionari e quello che ho capito è che "linea morbida" è l'opzione più flessibile o meno radicale, ma non sono sicura se questo è il significato che ha "linea morbida" nell'articolo.

Qualcuno può spiegarmi cosa significa questo termine o, magari, può darmi un'espressione equivalente in spagnolo o inglese?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it asks for translation into Spanish and should be asked on Spanish.StackExchange

Comment: @I.M.: But I think the OP is asking about the meaning of "linea morbida" and in that sense it would be on-topic.

Comment: I agree with Charo: this is asking for the meaning of an expression. Moreover I've been looking for *linea dura* in the dictionaries for ten minutes now and I cannot find it, so it is clearly not so easy for a non native speaker...

Comment: @Charo You're a moderator, you know better. :) I just think the OP might get the answer she needs much faster on Spanish.SE, since she needs not only the meaning but the meaning+translation.

Comment: @I.M. But if the OP does not get to understand the meaning, how can she ask about it in a non-Italian SE?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*Linea morbida* in questo caso è usato come antonimo di [*linea dura*](http://www.treccani.it/vocabolario/linea/)

> **Linea:** [...] programma o modo di comportamento: determinare, modificare la propria l. politica; adottare una l. dura, una l. morbida, o una l. di rinnovamento, di trasformazione, e sim.
>
> *(Dal dizionario Treccani)*

(dopo aver guardato in quattro dizionari, questo è il meglio che riesco a trovare: imbarazzante). Una *linea dura* è un atteggiamento severo verso un'infrazione o un crimine (simile all'inglese *hard line*).

In questo caso, fa riferimento ad un [precedente articolo](http://www.repubblica.it/motori/sezioni/sicurezza/2017/07/17/news/cellulare_alla_guida_passa_la_linea_morbida_-170969814/) in cui il giornalista si lamentava che, invece della promessa linea dura (vale a dire alta severità) verso l'uso del telefono al volante, il governo avesse passato una "linea morbida", cioè non sufficientemente severa (per la precisione, la sospensione della patente alla seconda infrazione e non alla prima come desiderato dalla Polizia Stradale).